# PHP - how to display data from database on categories highcharts?

Tags: php, sql, highcharts, categories

I Have a problem. How to display data from database on categories highcharts? I use combo dual axes. I need this for a college graduation. can someone help me?

I have used this

```
var data = {"name":"Percentage","data":[50,28,150,125,34,75]};
var categories = [<?php echo join($nama_tugas, ",") ?>];
```

but it is not working

```
$i = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_detail_tugas WHERE kode_mapel='$km' AND nip ='$nip'");                                    
while ($u = mysql_fetch_assoc($i)) {
    $d = $u['detail_id'];        
    echo  $d ;
    $a = mysql_query("SELECT AVG(nilai) AS jum FROM tbl_nilai WHERE tbl_nilai.detail_id = $d");
    while ($t = mysql_fetch_array($a)) {
        echo $t['jum'];
        $k[] = $t['jum'];                                               
     }


}

$aa = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_detail_tugas WHERE kode_mapel='$km' AND nip ='$nip'");

while ($uu = mysql_fetch_array($aa)) {
    $dd = $uu['detail_id'];

    $nama_tugas = $$uu['nama_tugas'];

    $ii = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_nilai WHERE tbl_nilai.detail_id = $dd AND nis ='$id'");
    while ($tt = mysql_fetch_array($ii)) {
        echo $tt['jum'];
        $kk[] = $tt['nilai'];                                               

    }


}


?>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

$('.dual').highcharts({
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Nilai Tugas & Nilai Rata-rata <?php echo $km ?>'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Sumber: SMK N2 Merangin'
    },
    xAxis: [{
    categories: []
        crosshair: true
    }],
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Nilai',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        }
    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        title: {
            text: 'aaa',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        opposite: true
    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        x: 120,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 100,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
    },
    series: [{

        name: 'nilai',
        type: 'column',
        yAxis: 0,
        data: data,
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        }

    },{
        name: 'Rata-rata',
        type: 'spline',
        yAxis: 0,
        data: [<?php echo join($k, ','); ?>],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        }
    }]
});
});
    </script>
```

Comment: paste your php call's response here

Comment: What your <?php echo join($k, ','); ?> returns / print ?

Comment: Its average of value...

Comment: What is php call's response?

Comment: Could you print what your <?php echo join($k, ','); ?> return? I mean [1,2,3] or something different?